# Permision to enable/disable a b2bunit

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I want that my newly created user (that doesn't belong to the admingroup) to have the permission to enable/disable a b2bunit from the editorareaactions - see picture.(I have the same problem for the b2bcustomer).I have already for my usergroup this permissions:

```
    $START_USERRIGHTS
                Type;UID;MemberOfGroups;Password;Target;read;change;create;delete;change_perm
                UserGroup;myGroup;;
                ;;;;AbstractComment;+;+;+;+;
                ;;;;AbstractOrder;+;;;;
                ;;;;AbstractOrderEntry;+;;;;
                ;;;;Address;+;+;+;+;
                ;;;;ArticleText;+;+;+;+;
                ;;;;B2BBudget;+;+;+;+;
                ;;;;B2BCostCenter;+;+;+;+;
                ;;;;B2BCustomer;+;+;+;+;-
                ;;;;B2BCustomerPunchOutCredentialMapping;+;+;+;+;
                ;;;;B2BPermission;+;+;+;+;
                ;;;;B2BUnit;+;+;+;+;
                ;;;;B2BUserGroup;+;+;+;+;
                ;;;;BackofficeSavedQuery;+;+;+;+;
                ;;;;BaseStore;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Cart;+;;;;
                ;;;;CartEntry;+;;;;
                ;;;;Catalog;+;;;;
                ;;;;CatalogVersion;+;;;;
                ;;;;Category;+;+;+;+;
                ;;;;CheckboxFormField;+;+;+;+;
                ;;;;ClassificationAttributeUnit;+;;;;
                ;;;;CMSItem;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;CMSSite;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Comment;+;+;+;+;
                ;;;;CompanyCodeAssignment;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Component;+;;;;
                ;;;;CommentType;+;;;;
                ;;;;CommentUserSetting;+;+;+;+;
                ;;;;CommentMetadata;+;+;+;+;
                ;;;;Consignment;+;;;;
                ;;;;ConsignmentEntry;+;;;;
                ;;;;CronJob;+;+;+;;
                ;;;;DateTimeFormField;+;+;+;+;
                ;;;;Domain;+;;;;
                ;;;;DropdownElement;+;+;+;+;
                ;;;;DropdownFormField;+;+;+;+;
                ;;;;Employee;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;FormConfiguration;+;+;+;+;
                ;;;;FormFieldLabel;+;+;+;+;
                ;;;;Item;+;+;+;+;
                ;;;;ItemSyncTimestamp;+;;;;
                ;;;;Job;+;+;+;;
                ;;;;JobLog;+;+;+;+;
                ;;;;CronJobHistory;+;+;+;+;
                ;;;;LookFeelSettingsConfig;+;+;+;+;
                ;;;;MaterialNumber;+;+;+;+;
                ;;;;NumberInputFormField;+;+;+;+;
                ;;;;PaymentInfo;+;;;;
                ;;;;PaymentTypeGroup;+;+;+;+;
                ;;;;Principal;+;;-;-;
                ;;;;Product;+;+;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.supercategories;+;+;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.name;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.catalogVersion;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.approvalStatus;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.ccManufacturerName;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.defaultAssortment;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.taxExemptDE;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.taxExemptAT;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.companyCodeAssignment;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.unit;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.orderableUntil;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.producAvailTextField;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.producAvailNumberOfDays;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.deliveryModes;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.onlineDate;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.offlineDate;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.purchasableFromDate;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.purchasableToDate;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.sapBlockedDate;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.description;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.summary;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.productReferences;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.europe1Prices;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.minOrderQuantity;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.maxOrderQuantity;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.priceQuantity;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.Europe1PriceFactory_PPG;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.Europe1PriceFactory_PTG;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.Europe1PriceFactory_PDG;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.europe1Discounts;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.picture;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.thumbnail;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.data_sheet;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.detail;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.logo;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.normal;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.others;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.thumbnails;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.galleryImages;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.documents;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.variantType;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.variants;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.ean;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.manufacturerAID;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.manufacturerName;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.deliveryTime;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.contentUnit;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.numberContentUnits;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.remarks;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.keywords;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.features;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.allDocuments;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.comments;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.endLineNumber;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.erpGroupBuyer;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.erpGroupSupplier;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.europe1Taxes;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.linkComponents;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.manufacturerTypeDescription;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.namedItem;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.order;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.orderQuantityInterval;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.ownEurope1Prices;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.ownEurope1Taxes;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.productDetailComponents;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.productFeatureComponents;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.productListComponents;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.productOrderLimit;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.restrictions;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.salesRanking;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.sapBaseUnitConversion;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.sapBlocked;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.sapConfigurable;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.sapEAN;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.sapPlant;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.segment;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.sequenceId;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.specialTreatmentClasses;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.startLineNumber;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.supplierAlternativeAID;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.unitOfMeasure;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.unspcs;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.vendors;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;Product.xmlcontent;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;ProductForAssortment;+;+;+;+;
                ;;;;ProductReference;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;PunchOutCredential;+;+;+;+;
                ;;;;Reply;+;+;+;+;
                ;;;;Quote;+;;;;
                ;;;;QuoteEntry;+;;;;
                ;;;;StandardPaymentMode;+;;;;
                ;;;;StyleAttributes;+;+;+;+;
                ;;;;SyncItemJob;+;;;;
                ;;;;TermsAndConditions;+;+;+;+;
                ;;;;TextInputFormField;+;+;+;+;
                ;;;;Type;+;;;;
                ;;;;Unit;+;-;-;-;
                ;;;;UserGroup;+;+;+;+;
                ;;;;VariantType;+;;;;
                ;;;;ZoneDeliveryMode;+;+;+;+;
                ;;;;WorkflowAction;+;+;+;+;
                ;;;;WorkflowActionTemplate;+;+;+;+;
                ;;;;WorkflowDecision;+;+;+;+;
                ;;;;WorkflowDecisionTemplate;+;+;+;+;
                ;;;;WorkflowItemAttachment;+;+;;;
                ;;;;WorkflowTemplate;+;+;+;+;
$END_USERRIGHTS
```

So my user sees the icons, but cannot trigger the action. What permission do I miss out or what I am doing wrong? Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user, you are trying to give access to perform this action, must be part of Admin group (*admingroup*) or B2BAdmin group (*b2badmingroup*). (as per OOB hybris *EnableB2BUnitAction*).

If you do not want this user to be part of any one of these groups, you have to override *EnableB2BUnitAction.canPerform* method to enable the action.

Please refer class :

```
 de.hybris.platform.b2bcommerce.backoffice.actions.EnableB2BUnitAction
```